# how to get the checkboxes check in custom plugin

Tags: custom-post-types

maybe this is a stupid question but I just can't figure it out. I have  a custom post type which has some submenus added. In one of the submenus I would like to add check boxes with the title of a custom post type. That is all working, it's showing the check boxes and the titles of CPTs, but my problem starts when I need to check the checkbox and remember the selection. 
I get the CPTs and add the check box:

```
    $bspposts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'badge' ) );
    foreach($bspposts as $bsppost){
        ?>
        <div><p><input type="checkbox" name="bsp_ba_title" value="<?php echo $bsppost->ID; ?>" 
        <?php checked( $bsppost->ID, $name ); ?> /><?php echo $bsppost->post_title; ?>
    </p></div>
        <?php
        }
```

But the check boxes are not getting the checked='checked' value when checked.

Comment: In checked() function, you are checking id ie. '$bsppost->ID' with '$name'. In your code '$name' is not defined.

Comment: I don't know with what to compare it because check boxes all have the same name because of the foreach. So do I compare it to the post_title or to what? @WisdmLabs

Comment: Why have you used $name?

Comment: I changed it to the $bsppost->ID, so now I get the checked='checked' but nothing happens when I uncheck it. I put name because of the name attribute (bsp_ba_title). @WisdmLabs

Comment: Please elaborate your code better. To understand what you are doing, you need to show how you save the values, and what happens after you checked the checkbox etc. With the information given, there is no way to guess what is actually the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to elaborate more. I got stuck in the checking of check boxes. If the check box isn't checked I can't do the rest of the code. So I got stuck in the first step. @fischi

Comment: What do you want to do with this list? You also create a lot of inputs with the same name, how do you want to know which one is checked? What is the checkbox supposed to do? How do you plan on saving the checkbox? ...

Comment: This list is a list of all CPTs and the user will have the option to choose just a few. And when the user chooses the ones he wants they will be attached to him (with user meta) and then shown in other page. Something like that. @fischi